# Can I pass a file descriptor over a 0mq (zeromq) ipc socket?

Tags: zeromq, file-descriptor, unix-socket

I have a master process and several workers, communicating using 0mq 'ipc://' sockets (UNIX domain sockets). I want to pass a file descriptor from the master to a worker, along with a message. I know that 'raw' UNIX domain sockets can be used to pass a file descriptor from one process to another, but can I do it with my zeromq sockets?

I don't care about portability, and frankly I don't care if its a slightly dirty solution. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hackiest method would be to add a socket option to bind a file descriptor to the socket, then replace the `send()` & `recv()` with `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()` per the required `CMSG` structure to pass the descriptor.

As a global option every message would be tagged with the descriptor thus you should add suitable meta-data within the payload to indicate that the receiver should take the accompanying descriptor.

e.g. send-side

```
zmq_setsockopt (s, ZMQ_ANCILLIARYFD, &fd, sizeof (fd));
```

e.g. recv side

```
int incoming_fd;
size_t fd_len = sizeof (incoming_fd);
zmq_getsockopt (s, ZMQ_ANCILLIARYFD, &incoming_fd, &fd_len);
```

Comment: i.e. you'll have to change the zmq source code, as zmq can't currently do this.

Comment: PS I didn't say in my original question that I'm using python binding, so @nos's comment is quite pertinent and may make any modification awkward - I'd rather not build something that can't be easily installed with pip. Thanks for the info Steve, I'll take a look and see what I see.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty certain the answer is No. A file descriptor is an integer that means something within the context of the process that called open(). In the context of another process it is meaningless. Passing that integer to another process by any method does not mean that that destination process can use it in a call to read().

File descriptors, pointers of type FILE*, anything like that are referencing objects that are almost always considered opaque. The opaqueness of that means that you can't copy it and expect it to work, which is effectively what you're trying to do by sending it through a pipe, socket, 0mq, etc.

Within a process the reference can be copied (and used by another thread for example).

The destination process can of course open the file for itself; all it needs is the filename.

Comment: No, you can pass file descriptors to other programs, its a common technique for (eg) web servers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket, http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/. Also destination cannot open the file descriptor for itself if (eg) it doesn't have permission to open that file or if it the file descriptor points to a socket. My master process is actually already receiving file descriptors from another process, I just need to pass them on to the workers (over 0mq).

Comment: I learn something every day! Apologies for the none-useful answer.

Comment: Hang on, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor hints that the file descriptor references a kernel data structure in which case I can see why sharing it would work. However http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ makes no mention of that. Doesn't that mean that sharing an fd in this way is not explicitly portable?