# Cross platform way to send socket to child process

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ipc

I'm trying to give an already running child process access to a socket I'm using in the parent process. This must be done in **C/C++** and on **Windows and Linux**. Currently I only know of *Unix domain sockets* for sending the socket's file descriptor to the child process which is perfectly suitable but only works on Linux. But I haven't found a solution that works on both platforms yet.

Comment: Have you looked at Boost? http://www.boost.org/

Comment: I looked at it briefly but I couldn't find a hint whether it is able to send TCP sockets on windows. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Your title is too broad. "IPC" = "InterProcess Communication", and also includes shared memory, pipes and other things.

What you want is just a network library. You should check Boost.Asio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C/C++ Network Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Comment: Have you tried D-bus, it is Linux and Windows

Comment: @Brandin I'm currently using D-bus with Qt and I don't really need Qt for this but I couldn't find whether D-Bus for windows can send sockets.

Comment: @Synxis As it seemd Boost.Asio can only send sockets over Unix Domain Sockets which doesn't work on windows

Comment: Boost.Asio works perfectly fine on Windows.

Comment: @HardcorEViruS It sounds like you need a network library like others mentioned. For a simple solution you could look at Apache Portable Runtime it has network IO socket functions

Comment: ZeroMQ might be another contender http://zeromq.org/

Comment: @Nick As per [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15670098/2560791) ZeroMQ doesn't have the capabilities to send sockets at least on windows

Comment: @Synxis Boost.Asio seems to only be able to send socket file descriptors on Linux using Unix Domain Sockets but not on Windows

Comment: @HardcorEViruS I see you've changed your question - it wasn't clear originally what you were trying to do. I've flagged it for reopening but you'll need more voters. Alternatively ask a new question.

Comment: I agree with Nick, I voted to reopen it.

Comment: Look at `WSADuplicateSocket`.